# Android pass parent view's 'pressed' state to child views

Tags: android, xml-layout

There are many question here on SO asking for a way to *prevent* a child view from copying its parents pressed or selected states.
However, I'm asking for the other way around here :) - I've seen a very weird behavior in one of my apps:

When running the App on a 4.0.4 device (API 15) the behavior I saw matched the apparent default, which is: The parent forwards its state down to all of its child views.

When running the same App without any changes on a higher API level (Android 4.4) this behavior changes: The parent does NOT forward its state.

I introduced `duplicateParentState` in the xml layout for all relevant child views, but this does not seem to help here.

Is this a known 'issue' or a planned change in behavior from API 15 to API >> 15?
How can I make sure the states are properly forwarded across all API levels?

If it is of any help / relevance here: The subview I want to duplicate its parents state is a custom `ImageView` which adds tintColors - Since the behavior is correct on 4.0.4 there should not be any mistakes in this class?

```
public class INCImageView extends ImageView {

    private int _tintColor;
    private int _highlightedTintColor;
    private int _selectedTintColor;

    public INCImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setClickable(true);

        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.INCImageView);

        _tintColor = array.getInt(R.styleable.INCImageView_tintColor, getResources().getColor(R.color.inc_tint));
        this.setColorFilter(_tintColor);

        _selectedTintColor = array.getInt(R.styleable.INCImageView_selectedTintColor, _tintColor);
        _highlightedTintColor = array.getInt(R.styleable.INCImageView_highlightedTintColor, _tintColor);

        array.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        super.setSelected(selected);

        this.setColorFilter((selected ? _selectedTintColor : _tintColor));
    }

    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        super.setPressed(pressed);

        this.setColorFilter((pressed ? _highlightedTintColor : (this.isSelected() ? _selectedTintColor : _tintColor)));
    }
}
```

Comment: should work,  can you reverse the `super.set...` and `setColorFilter` method order?

Comment: yes I can reverse it. - tested and still the same issue :(

Comment: :( indeed,  can you confirm that the INCImageView parent is also focusable and clickable?

Comment: yes - all parents of the imageView are focusable + clickable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

If you have a look at the `ImageView` subclass above, in the constructor `clickable` & `focusable` are set to `true`.

Turns out this was the mistake. The parent won't forward its state when the child itself is clickable. - That still does not explain why the above code works on 4.0.4 but breaks on 4.4

Anyway, leaving the `clickable & focusable = false` solves the problem.

Comment: You can only accept answers to your own question that you wrote yourself after 2 days -.-